# TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a bot for discord and I ran into a problem that the bot does not start, I would appreciate it if you could help me). The bot was created in python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import  token

import  youtube_dl
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot online!')

@bot.event()
async def on_message():
    print('New Message!')

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: You use `@bot.event()` for one decorator and `@bot.event` for the other. Is this intentional?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro' discord python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869121/typeerror-event-missing-1-required-positional-argument-coro-discord-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `@bot.event` decorator for events. Not `@bot.event()`.
Also `on_message` function should has 1 argument. So, you need to write `

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    pass  # whatever here
```